# How to set a GridSplitter to a specific initial position?

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I'm using a `GridSplitter` in my WPF application and would like to set it to a specific initial position from code. I'm stuck with the behaviour of the `GridSplitter` when setting a specific value to the `Height` property of the associated `RowDefinition`.

Here's my example to illustrate the problem. I have added `TextBlocks` to display the acual values of the `RowDefinition.Height` properties.

#### XAML code:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDef1" Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDef2" Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" >
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Text="Upside Height: "/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Tbl1" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Height}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Background="Black" />
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" LastChildFill="True" >
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Downside Height: "/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Tbl2" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Height}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

#### Codebehind:

```
namespace WpfGridSplitterTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Tbl1.DataContext = this.RowDef1;
            Tbl2.DataContext = this.RowDef2;

        }
    }
}
```

The result works as expected. The `GridSplitter` resizes both parts of the window, obeys the `MinHeight` values and stops at the window borders. Resizing the window also works as designed :-)

Now I'm trying to set the initial position for the `GridSplitter` from codebehind like this:

```
    InitializeComponent();

    RowDef1.Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    Tbl1.DataContext = this.RowDef1;
    Tbl2.DataContext = this.RowDef2;
```

The result is weired:

- The `GridSplitter` is initially set to 50 px from the top (that's fine)
- It stops at the upper rows `MinHeight` of 20px (that's also fine)

but

- it does no longer respect the lower boundary of the window nor the `MinHeight` value for the lower row
- `ActualHeight` values for the lower row are not longer updated when the GridSplitter is moved

What am I missing here? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

I have read this post, yet the answer doesn't work in my case:
[How to set initial height of a GridSplitter 'pane'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662978/how-to-set-initial-height-of-a-gridsplitter-pane)

Changing `Height="*"` to `Height="Auto"` isn't fixing the problem either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting RowDef1's height to 50 **PIXEL**. What you want to do is set it to something **STAR**. But what value of star?

Since you want RowDef1 to end up at 50 pixels then you need to calculate the space available to RowDef1/2 in pixels. Assign 50 to RowDef1 in STAR units and the assign the remaining to RowDef2 in STAR units.

```
InitializeComponent();

Tbl1.DataContext = this.RowDef1;
Tbl2.DataContext = this.RowDef2;

this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
  var height = RowDef1.ActualHeight + RowDef2.ActualHeight; // 301 pixels
  RowDef1.Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star); // 50*
  RowDef2.Height = new GridLength(height - 50, GridUnitType.Star); // 251*
};
```